# RTL8723BE wifi problem ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, 15.04

I've recently bought a Lenovo Thinkpad E440 laptop. Everything works  fine except for the WiFi card. I've already installed the github driver and ran this command:

```
 echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

and downloaded the driver from [here](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new).

but still no case. Connection drops after a few hours of usage.

Here I ran `lspci` command to get more information of my wireless card:

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Sorry for my bad English.

Thanks.

Comment: I use kernel version 4.0.4-040004-generic as said by the  uname -r command.